# R Shiny. How to make selectinput choices reactive to each other while subsetting data

Tags: r, shiny, subset, dropdown, reactive

I am looking for a way for users to subset data based on inputted values of multiple variables, for example name and age, but once a choice has been made in one input the other dropdowns should be reactive and only provide choices that correspond with the already chosen input. I have it working going from "name" to "age," but I would also like it to work the other way, if "age" is chosen first. I've posted my code below.

```
l <- NULL;
l$name <- c('b','e','d','b','b','d','e')
l$age <- c(20,20,21,21,20,22,22)
l <- as.data.frame(l)
l <- as_data_frame(l)
l$name <- as.character(l$name)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){

assign('All Names',unique(sort(l$name)))
assign("All Ages", unique(sort(l$age)))
data1 <- reactive(l[which(l$name %in% if(exists(input$name))
{get(input$name)}else{input$name}),])

output$Box1 =  renderUI(
if(is.null(input$name) || input$name == "All Names"){
selectInput("name", "Choose Name", choices=c(c("All Names"), 
unique(sort(l$name))))
 }else{selectInput("name", "Choose Name", choices=c(input$name,c("All 
Names")))}
)

output$Box2 =  renderUI(
  if(is.null(input$age) || input$age == "All Ages"){
  selectInput("age", "Choose Age", choices=c("All Ages", 
unique(sort(data1()$age))))
  }else{ selectInput("age", "Choose Age", choices=c(input$age, "All Ages"))}
  )
output$table1 <- renderTable(data1())
output$text1 <- renderPrint(input$name)
data2 <- reactive(data1()[which(data1()$age %in% if(exists(input$age))
{get(input$age)}else{input$age}),])
output$table2 <- renderTable(data2())

})

ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(
uiOutput("Box1"),
uiOutput("Box2")
,tableOutput("table1"),
textOutput("text1"),
tableOutput("table2")
))

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

For example, when the user chooses "b" for the name, only "20" and "21" show up as "age" choices, but then once one of those ages is clicked, I would like the choices in the "name" dropdown to react and only show options with the chosen age.

Any suggestions would be really appreciated!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44570404/updating-filters-in-shiny-app Same problem than you

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want (if not tell me I'll try to find how I can help you):

```
l <- NULL
l$name <- c('b','e','d','b','b','d','e')
l$age <- c(20,20,21,21,20,22,22)
l <- as.data.frame(l)
l$name <- as.character(l$name)
library(shiny)


server <- shinyServer(function(input,output){



  data1 <- reactive({


    if(input$Box1 == "All" & input$Box2 == "All"){
    l
    }else if (input$Box1 == "All" & input$Box2 != "All"){
  l[which(l$age == input$Box2),]  
    }else if (input$Box1 != "All" & input$Box2 == "All"){
      l[which(l$name == input$Box1),]  
    }else{
      l[which(l$name == input$Box1 & l$age==input$Box2),]
    }
  })


output$table1 <- renderPrint({
  data1()}
  )

})

ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("Box1","Choose name :", choices = c('All',unique(l$name))),
  selectInput("Box2","Choose age :", choices = c('All',unique(l$age))),
  verbatimTextOutput("table1")
))

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: It's creating the correct subset, but I would like the dropdown menus to only have choices that correspond to the already chosen variables. So if "b" is chosen, age would only have options of "20" and "21", and if "21" was chosen, name would only have options of "b" and "d"

Comment: Ok sorry, my mistake. Did you try with the observe() function ?

Comment: I've tried using Observe() to make a list of unique(sort(data3()$name)) and using this as the choices for the dropdown, but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I think I found how to do. Check my last answer

Answer (score 1):

I've got finnaly this :

I think this is what you are looking for ? tell me !

```
l <- NULL
l$name <- c('b','e','d','b','b','d','e')
l$age <- c(20,20,21,21,20,22,22)
l <- as.data.frame(l)
l$name <- as.character(l$name)
l$age <- as.numeric(l$age)
library(shiny)

server <- shinyServer(function(input,output, session){

  data1 <- reactive({
    if(input$Box1 == "All"){
      l
    }else{
      l[which(l$name == input$Box1),]
    }
  })

  data2 <- reactive({
    if (input$Box2 == "All"){
      l
    }else{
      l[which(l$age == input$Box2),]
    }
  })

  observe({

    if(input$Box1 != "All"){
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box2","Choose an age", choices = c("All",unique(data1()$age)))
    }

    else if(input$Box2 != 'All'){
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box1","Choose a name", choices = c('All',unique(data2()$name)))
    }

    else if (input$Box1 == "All" & input$Box2 == "All"){
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box2","Choose an age", choices = c('All',unique(l$age)))
      updateSelectInput(session,"Box1","Choose a name", choices = c('All',unique(l$name)))
    }
  })


  data3 <- reactive({
    if(input$Box2 == "All"){
      data1()
    }else if (input$Box1 == "All"){
      data2()
    }else if (input$Box2 == "All" & input$Box1 == "All"){
      l
    }
    else{
      l[which(l$age== input$Box2 & l$name == input$Box1),]
    }
  })

  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    data3()
  })


})



ui <-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  selectInput("Box1","Choose a name", choices = c("All",unique(l$name))),
  selectInput("Box2","Choose an age", choices = c("All",unique(l$age))),
  tableOutput("table1")
))

shinyApp(ui,server)
```